# How to dynamically add remove and delete labels created in a for loop from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to display a list of users saved in a text file on a line by line basis and have it updated as people launch and close my program respectively. I can't figure out how to update the labels as in create new ones and delete ones no longer present in the text file as I can't `.set()` or `.config()` them as far as I know since the actual text on the labels doesn't have to change.

Here is my code so far.

```
def list_users(self):
    with open("usercheck.txt", "r") as ulst:
        self.usr_list = []
        for line in ulst:
            self.usr_list.append(line)

def online(self):
    for self.name in self.usr_list:
        self.onlbl = tk.Label(self, text = self.name,bg = "#42f480")
        self.onlbl.grid(row = self.onlcnt,column = 5,padx = 0)
        self.onlcnt +=1
```

Running the `online` function with `after` just creates duplicates of the same label and does not update the amount of labels. `self.onlcnt` is 0

Comment: It would help if you posted a [mcve], including a small sample "usercheck.txt" so that we could run your program and reproduce the problem. Also, "have it updated as people launch and close my program respectively" is a bit unclear. Do you mean when people  launch and close this Tkinter program itself, or are you talking about some other program?

Comment: I mean the tkinter program itself. the text file in question is just a list of names on different lines eg:
douglas
Ben
James. formatting doesnt really carry on comments. each name has its own line though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that you are using the `self` keyword in your loop variable, which causes the variable to stay constant: don’t.

```
def online(self):
    for name in self.usr_list:
        self.onlbl = tk.Label(self, text = name,bg = "#42f480")
        self.onlbl.grid(row = self.onlcnt,column = 5,padx = 0)
        self.onlcnt +=1
```

Also you might want to store the `Labels` in a `list`, so you can access them later:

```
def online(self):
    try:
        self.labels
    except AttributeError:
        self.labels = []
    self.onlcnt = 0
    for name in self.usr_list:
        onlbl = tk.Label(self, text = name,bg = "#42f480")
        onlbl.grid(row = self.onlcnt,column = 5,padx = 0)
        self.labels.append(onlbl)
        self.onlcnt +=1
    root.after(5000, self.online) #run it again
```

Comment: Not sure if its a different version of python but NameError is AttributeError: for me. I don't know how to update the labels dynamically though as they are still created by the for loop in "onlbl = ..." I need the labels to be updated every few seconds. Sorry if I am missing something obvious here –